# GCP: Duplicate an existing project in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to duplicate an entire project?
The project contains:
2x Cloud SQL: main + backup
1x Cloud Storage
4x Google Compute Engine

We have an exactly the same project already built up and configured, so it would be much easier for us if we could just make a copy of those.

The projects are not under the same account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such a way to replicate as-is a project.
However, you can use [Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) starting from your current project: this CLI tool will generate [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) template files starting from the existing infrastructure (reverse Terraform). Then, you can use these files to re-create the target resources within a second GCP project in a programmatic fashion (see https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-on-gcp-with-terraform).

---

*Disclaimer: Comments and opinions are my own and not the views of my employer.*