# Duplicating GCP Network and VPN Configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud, vpn

I have two GCP projects communicating with each over over a Classic VPN, I'd like to duplicate this entire configuration to another GCP account with two projects. So in addition to the tunnels and gateways, I have one network in each project to duplicate, some firewall rules, and a custom routing rule on one project.

I've found how I can largely dump these using various

```
gcloud compute [networks | vpn-tunnels | target-vpn-gateways] describe
```

commands, but looking at the create commands they don't seem setup to be piped to, nor use this output data as a file, not to mention there are some items that won't be applicable in the new projects.

I'm not just trying to save time, I'm trying to make sure I don't miss anything and I also want a hard copy of sorts, of my current configuration.

Is there any way to do this?  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified in other similar cases - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289435/gcp-duplicate-an-existing-project-in-google-cloud-platform) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63889531/it-is-possible-to-duplicate-a-complete-google-cloud-project-with-minimal-manual) - it's not possible to clone or duplicate entire projects in Google Cloud Platform. As explained in these other cases, you can use [Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) as to generate Terraform files from existing infrastructure (reverse Terraform) and then, recreate the files in your new instance as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-on-gcp-with-terraform).

To summarize, you can try this CLI as a possible alternative to copy part of your structure, but as emphasized in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63890952/12767257), there is no automatic way or magic tool that will copy everything, so even your VMs configuration, your app contents, your data content, won't be duplicated.